# grep data and add it at the end of a line

Tags: shell-script, awk, grep

I have a .dat file like this:

```
show version
Cisco IOS Software, C2960 Software (C2960-LANBASE-M), Version 12.2(35)SE5, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Copyright (c) 1986-2007 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Thu 19-Jul-07 20:06 by nachen
Image text-base: 0x00003000, data-base: 0x00D40000

ROM: Bootstrap program is C2960 boot loader
BOOTLDR: C2960 Boot Loader (C2960-HBOOT-M) Version 12.2(25r)SEE6, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

Electronica_Edif_3 uptime is 17 weeks, 6 days, 0 minutes
System returned to ROM by power-on
System restarted at 13:04:50 gmt Thu Nov 10 2016
System image file is "flash:c2960-lanbase-mz.122-35.SE5/c2960-lanbase-mz.122-35.SE5.bin"

cisco WS-C2960-48TC-L (PowerPC405) processor (revision F0) with 61440K/4088K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID FOC1235Z1W5
Last reset from power-on
2 Virtual Ethernet interfaces
48 FastEthernet interfaces
2 Gigabit Ethernet interfaces
 --More--         The password-recovery mechanism is enabled.

64K bytes of flash-simulated non-volatile configuration memory.
Base ethernet MAC Address       : 00:23:05:46:8B:00
Motherboard assembly number     : 73-9835-09
Power supply part number        : 341-0097-02
Motherboard serial number       : FOC12351HVZ
Power supply serial number      : AZS123206WY
Model revision number           : F0
Motherboard revision number     : A0
Model number                    : WS-C2960-48TC-L
System serial number            : FOC1235Z1W5
Top Assembly Part Number        : 800-26672-04
Top Assembly Revision Number    : A0
Version ID                      : V04
CLEI Code Number                : COM3F00BRC
Hardware Board Revision Number  : 0x02


Switch   Ports  Model              SW Version              SW Image            
------   -----  -----              ----------              ----------          
*    1   50     WS-C2960-48TC-L    12.2(35)SE5             C2960-LANBASE-M     

 --More--         
Configuration register is 0xF

Electronica_Edif_3>
```

I would like to grep System serial number from that and add it at the end of a certain line in a .cvs like this:

```
device_id,ip_address
 BIOTERIO, 148.000.00.189
 N7K-LAN(JAF1651ANDL), 148.000.0.192
 LAB_PESADO, 148.000.000.130
 Arquitectura_Salones, 148.000.000.61
 CIVIL_253, 148.000.000.253
 Arquitectura, 148.000.000.253
 ING_CIVIL, 148.000.000.251
 ING_CIVIL_DIR, 148.000.0.188
 Ingenieria_Posgrado, 148.000.000.253
 Biblio_Barragan, 148.000.000.61
 Electronica_Edif_3, 148.000.000.253
```

So for example, in this case I would like to extract SN and add it at line No. 12 (I already have this number in a variable)I should look like this:

```
device_id,ip_address
 BIOTERIO, 148.000.00.189
 N7K-LAN(JAF1651ANDL), 148.000.0.192
 LAB_PESADO, 148.000.000.130
 Arquitectura_Salones, 148.000.000.61
 CIVIL_253, 148.000.000.253
 Arquitectura, 148.000.000.253
 ING_CIVIL, 148.000.000.251
 ING_CIVIL_DIR, 148.000.0.188
 Ingenieria_Posgrado, 148.000.000.253
 Biblio_Barragan, 148.000.000.61
 Electronica_Edif_3, 148.000.000.253,FOC1235Z1W5
```

Could you help me?

I Know how to grep SN and store it into a variable:
`SN="grep "System serial number" SN_148.228.130.253.dat | sed 's/^.*: //'"`

but I don't know how to add that into a given line.

Comment: I Know how to grep SN and store it into a variable:
SN="grep "System serial number" SN_148.228.130.253.dat | sed 's/^.*: //'"

but i don't know how to add that into a given line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a one-liner, but this is pretty easy to understand. Just pass the line number and serial numbers as variables to your final `awk` call. Check if the line number matches, and add the extra info if it does!

```
#!/bin/sh
line=12
sn=$(awk '/System serial number/ {print $5}' SN_148.228.130.253.dat)

awk -v "ln=$line" -v "sn=$sn" '{print (NR==ln) ? $0","sn : $0;}' csvfile
```

Comment: It works, but i would like to overwrite csvfile, I mean, at the end of the process, CSV file should have SN in the correct line.

Comment: Just redirect output to a temp file and move it

Answer (score 1):

This should work and does not require extra grep. Serial is extracted by datfile and added to the csv file , all in one script.

```
#!/bin/bash
line=12
awk -v line=$line 'BEGIN{FS=":"}NR==FNR{if ($1 ~ /System serial number/) \
{sn=$2;nextfile} else {next}}{FS=",";if (FNR==line) $0=$1 FS $2 FS sn}1' datfile cvsfile
```

**[See online test here.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMWEU3UlJlQ3hpYzg)**

Comment: @Cesar Updated,tested and working

Comment: @don_crissti yes... good point

Comment: @don_crissti I'm sure that sed can do it, but i dont know how to do it... i prefer awk :-)

Comment: `sed 12s/\$/,"$(sed 's/System serial number *: //;tt;d;:t;q' datfile1)"/ csvfile` is one of many ways with `sed`...